# Is there an elegant or easier way to solve this system of equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, physics

This is a physics problem that involves an inelastic collision and a system of equations that I want to solve. I know the values of $v_1,m_1,v',\Delta E$ where $v'$ is the velocity of the two objects after they stick together. I want to solve the equations for either $m_2$**(only in terms of $v_1,v',m_1, \Delta E$)** or for $v_2$ **(only in terms of ($v_1,v',m_1, \Delta E$)** but I am stuck because the terms get very messy.

$$m_1v_1+m_2v_2=(m_1+m_2)v' \tag{1}$$

$$\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2=\frac{1}{2}m_1(v')^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2(v')^2+\Delta E \tag{2}$$

My attempt so far:

Solving$(1)$ for $v_2$:

$$\implies v_2=\frac{m_1}{m_2}(v'-v_1)+v' \tag{1a}$$

Plug $(1a)$ into $(2)$:

$$\implies \frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2(\frac{m_1}{m_2}(v'-v_1)+v')^2=\frac{1}{2}m_1(v')^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2(v')^2+\Delta E \\ \iff \frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2 \left[\frac{m_1^2}{m_2^2 }(v'-v_1)^2+2\frac{m_1}{m_2}v'(v'-v_1)+(v')^2 \right]=\frac{1}{2}m_1(v')^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2(v')^2 +\Delta E\\ \iff \frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2+\frac{1}{2} m_2\left[ \left( \frac{m_1}{m_2}\right)^2((v')^2-2v'v_1-v_1^2)+2\left( \frac{m_1}{m_2}\right )((v'^2)-v_1v')+(v')^2\right] \\=\frac{1}{2}m_1(v')^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2(v')^2+\Delta E \\ \iff ...?$$

> Is there an easier way to do this? How do I even continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align} 
m_1v_1+m_2v_2&=(m_1+m_2)v' 
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2
&=
\frac{1}{2}m_1(v')^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2(v')^2+\Delta E 
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
\eqref{1}:\quad
m_2(v_2-v')&=
m_1(v'-v_1)
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
\eqref{2}:\quad
m_2(v_2^2-v'^2)&=
m_1(v'^2-v_1^2)+2\Delta E
\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

\eqref{3}$\times (v_2+v')-$\eqref{4}$\quad\Rightarrow$

\begin{align} 
0&=
m_1(v'-v_1)(v_2+v')-(m_1(v'^2-v_1^2)+2\Delta E)
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
v_2 &= v_1+\frac{2\Delta E}{m_1(v'-v_1)}
\tag{6}\label{6}
.
\end{align}

Comment: That's awesome! I would have never multiplied the third equation  by $(v_2+v')$ that's such a cool way to do it. Thank you very much! (How do I get better at this?)